# Creating new dictionaries as variables in a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, variables, dictionary

I'm working on a program for a class project that takes user input and creates a new dictionary that is then added to a list. I'm stuck on how to create new dictionary names for each entry and figured using variables to alter the name would be a good answer to the problem (I.E. dictx where x is the entry index) however, researching this solution has shown me that creating variable names using variables is considered a bad idea. So is there a simple way to create new dictionaries and add them to the list?

Comment: If you want a name for them, make a dict of dicts. If you don't need a name, just append the dicts to a list.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519795/creating-a-object-with-a-string/42520170?noredirect=1#comment72178053_42520170) is dealing with a closely related problem.  I don't know that it's quite close enough to flag this as a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It is hard to tell exactly what you are looking for and this isn't a code writing service. Please review [ask] and add some specifics, preferably a [mcve]: input, output expected, output you got from your attempt.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you have example code you have tried? One thing you should know: lists do not store the names of variables you have added to them; they store the contents of the variable. So you can say `lst=[]` and `dct = {'a': 1}` then `lst.append(dct)` then `dct = {'b': 3}` and `lst.append(dct)`. Both of the dictionaries will be appended to `lst`, and Python won't care if you assign something else to `dct` after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your keys to the list just with:

```
myList=[]
for key in MyDict.keys():
    myList.append(key)
```

Comment: This misses virtually every step listed in the already ambiguous question. Where is user input? Where do you create `MyDict`? It's better to wait for clarification on the question before posting an answer.

Comment: I just gave him a general way to create a list from keys dictionary. 
But indeed some clarifications will be appreciate.

Comment: `myList = list(MyDict.keys())` would be a better general way to do this.